# Allow semantic to parse only current buffer

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

When editing a C file in emacs with semantic-mode, Is there a way to prevent semantic to recursively parse included files, and only allow it to parse the current buffer?
I like some functionalities of semantic that only require parsing the current buffer (highlighting...), while I use rtags for navigation. I do not want to turn semantic off, but since parsing is extremely slow and blocks emacs, I would like to avoid it.

Comment: did you enable `global-semanticdb-minor-mode` as part of your `semantic-default-modes`? If so, then the parsing results should be stored in a database and it will only be slow the first time you parse all the normal includes. It does seem like it could be done without blocking though.

Comment: Yes, I enabled it. But I don't like that it's slow even the first time. It can take up to half an hour,...

Comment: huh, it only takes a few seconds on my machine (emacs 27, linux)

Comment: I guess it depends on how big the project is?

Comment: Even including boost/many system includes etc. should barely be noticeable. Are you on windows? I think I remember it being really slow on windows, but I can't remember why.

Comment: nope, linux. I have the last emacs version on debian sid.

Comment: maybe it's related to the many error messages "Error: (wrong-type-argument symbolp #<overlay ..." which I get